# Delayed searchable jobs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background, delayed-job, delayed-execution

Is there some background processor in ruby which would allow to find an existing not started delayed jobs by custom key?

I'm trying to solve a task with e-mail notifications, when there could be multiple changes in my model and I want to collect them in batches before sending.

So, I don't want to create another notification job when there is already an existing job, I'd rather append notification info to the existing job.

Any hint?

Thanks,
 KIR

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you will need an engine app

https://github.com/trevorturk/delayed_job_admin

Tested and working fine, but requires rails 3.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but I don't think this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm trying to mix concepts here.

Delayed Job's work is to run long tasks.

What I'm looking for is a list of active notifications, which I can easily implement with a custom table.